# SimplePie does not show Google RSS feeds

Tags: php, simplepie

I'm using SimplePie to fetch RSS feeds. All other RSS feeds are displaying except Google RSS. I checked by `echo $feed->error()`, the error shows

> This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML
>   error: EntityRef: expecting ';' at line 1, column 248

Comment: What is in the XML document at line 1?

Comment: RSS xml is:http://news.google.co.in/news?hl=en&gl=in&q=Akhilesh+Yadav&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Comment: rss xml is here  http://news.google.co.in/news?hl=en&gl=in&q=Akhilesh+Yadav&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the https for http. I had the same problem, and I tried the RSS xml that Inj2011 posted (aone of the commentators). When I looked at his feed and mine, the difference was the protocol. Then I used http, instead of https, and voila...

Answer (score 0):

Use "$feed->set_raw_data()" instead of "$feed->set_feed_url()", example :

```
$feed->set_raw_data(file_get_contents($rssurl));
```